# Invert a date to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a application that have multiple languages,in Portuguese and Spanish it uses `DD/MM/YYYY` and for english i need to make `MM/DD/YYYY`. I'm using this.

```
if (Culture == "English (United States)")
{
    var dataInicial = DateTime.ParseExact(dtini.ToString(), "MM-dd-yyyy h:mm tt", null);
    var dataFinal = DateTime.ParseExact(dtfim.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy h:mm tt", null);
}
```

But its not working,it is giving

> " String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

i tried "MM-dd-yyyy h:mm tt" and "dd-MM-yyyy h:mm tt",but got the same error.

---

The first question its done,now i have a invert problem,string to a datetime.Inside the grdCount.Cells[2].Text i have "15/12/2015"i want to convert to 12/15/2015 ,but i'm getting "String was not a recognized as a valid Datetime"

```
if (Culture== "English (United States)")
                    {
                        DateTime data = Convert.ToDateTime(grdCount.Cells[2].Text);
                        var dataInicial = data.ToString("mm-DD-yyyy");

                        _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["DTEMISSAO"] = grdCount.Cells[2].Text;
                        _simulacao.Notas.Rows[u]["DTVENCIMENTO"] = grdCount.Cells[3].Text;
                    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should treat in your code all dates using invariant culture, then present them with a specific culture (that'll ease the process for you).

Comment: What are the values of `Culture`, `dtini` and your `CurrentCulture` exactly?

Comment: It almost looks like your intent is to take an *existing* date value and alter its appearance. If that is the case, you would not use `DateTime.ParseExact`, you would display it using custom formatting, such as a `dtini.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` (this assumes that `dtini` and `dtfim` are already `DateTime` variables)

Comment: what about  "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt" and "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt"  ? did you tried it ?

Comment: In culture only has English (United States)     dtini has "{08/31/2016 12:00:00 AM}" and i dont use currentCulture,its better to use?

Comment: @ViniciusCano Your `dtini` seems _already_ a `Datetime`, that's why you might not _even_ need to parse anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the "general" DateTime format specifier ("g" and/or "G").

```
string formatted = myDateTime.ToString("g");
```

This will do the heavy lifting for you and output the "general" (as it's called) date format based on the culture of the user's machine. Here are the results as copied from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) page:

```
2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM (en-US)
2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 15/06/2009 13:45:30 (es-ES)
2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 2009/6/15 13:45:30 (zh-CN)
```

You can use this format in your call to DateTime.ToString() and get a culturally appropriate string to parse.

As an aside, based on your example you may consider just ditching this string conversion altogether. It seems like all you are doing is taking a DateTime and converting it to a string so that you can convert it back into a date time, and this is unnecessary, unless `dtini` and `dtfim` (what do those represent?) are some sort of weird user input objects.

Comment: Good answer, taught me something new. Downside might be a Spanish speaker on an American machine, so I can see the benefit of handling with application logic, but definitely a cool trick.

Comment: Thanks. Always best to let the framework do the job, right? :P

That said, the culture of the current machine is set independently of geographical location. So a Spanish user would most likely be using windows (for example) in spanish, thus they would get a "spanish" date and time format. If they were using the en-us culture, it would display a US english format.

Answer (score 0):

Change your date date time format, make the hour double digit `hh`

```
MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt
```

and

```
dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Aybe suggests, try treating the dates with invariant culture. That or force the UI elements you're using to use the current culture formatting: [CultureInfo.DateaTimeFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat(v=vs.110).aspx).